# Is it possible to define JNDI resources via Spring and, if "yes", how?

Tags: java, jetty, jndi

I'm working with a semi-legacy application that's made up of multiple modules coming as trasitive dependencies. To an extent, things have been migrated to Spring (in certain places more successfully than in others).

What I'd like to do is drop the JNDI configuration from the `jetty-env.xml`, as well as out WAS config and have this all handled via Spring. I've successfully migrated things like the datasource configuration to be handled by Spring, I've also dropped most of the XML-contexts and replaced them with annotations (wherever possible). Certains parts of the application are handled in transitive dependencies (which I should not be changing at the moment) and some of the code in them refers to JNDI environment entries like these:

```
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry">
    <Arg>someFoo</Arg>
    <Arg type="java.lang.String">someBlah</Arg>
</New>
```

I'd like to drop all this and let Spring handle it. Is it possible to control this from Spring entirely entirely?